# Javascript have a function return no value

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I've been trying to make a function that will not return any value if two values are the same between two arrays. I've searched my question several ways on here and on google, and everything I find says that a function HAS to return a value, and there's no way to avoid doing it. So I'm directly asking if there is a way, and if not how can I get around what I'm trying to do?

```js
var bannedValues = [2, 4, 6, 8]; //Even numbers 1-8
var inputValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]; //All numbers 1-8

var filterValues = function(value) 
{
  for (var number of bannedValues) 
  {
    if (value == number) 
    {
      return; //I want this to return absolutely nothing, not even an empty value
    }
  }
  return value;
}

var filteredValues = inputValues.map(filterValues);

console.log(filteredValues); 
/* The array just gains "undefined" values in the places I want there 
to be no value, so the array is a length of 8 instead of the 4 I want. 
Can I somehow take those out or can I just not have them there in the first place? */
```

Comment: You have to deal with it returning undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using map, you are actually iterating through your array and manipulate it if necessary, but this will not remove item from array. Instead of map try filter

```
var bannedValues = [2, 4, 6, 8]; //Even numbers 1-8
var inputValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]; //All numbers 1-8

var filterValues = function(value) {
  return bannedValues.indexOf(value)===-1;
}

var filteredValues = inputValues.filter(filterValues);

console.log(filteredValues);
```

result will be

```
(4) [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: The callback inside array.filter should return true/false.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Array.filter()` method:

```
var bannedValues = [2, 4, 6, 8]; //Even numbers 1-8
var inputValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]; //All numbers 1-8

filteredValues = inputValues.filter( function( el ) {
  return bannedValues.indexOf( el ) < 0;
} );

/*This is another way to do it, but not supported in IE*/
filteredValues = inputValues.filter( function( el ) {
  return !bannedValues.includes( el );
} );

console.log(filteredValues);
```

Lodash has an utility function for this as well: [see here](https://lodash.com/docs#difference)

Comment: Array.prototype.includes is not supported by IE, as well as Android. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript functions *always* have a return value. There's nothing you can do about that.

It's impossible I think to tell the difference between a function that explicitly returns `undefined` and one that just returns with no value expression.

If you want to do something *like* `.map()` but have the option of skipping values, use `.reduce()` instead:

```
var filterValues = function(accumulator, value) 
{
  for (var number of bannedValues) 
  {
    if (value == number) 
    {
      return accumulator;
    }
  }
  accumulator.push(value);
  return accumulator;
}

var filteredValues = inputValues.reduce(filterValues, []);
```

Comment: I looked at a page that explains `.reduce()` and from what I read it puts it into a single value, and your example isn't clear to me based on how I understand `.reduce()`. Can you clarify for somebody that is relatively new to JS? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp Is the page I used, and it says it only outputs one thing, whereas I just want to take things out.

Comment: @JoshuaCF my example *does* just return one value, but that value is an *array*. Basically you can use `.reduce()` to implement `.map()`, but it's more flexible. The `.map()` function is for when you always want a 1-to-1 relationship between the input array and the result array. With `.reduce()`, you can return whatever you want. In this sample, the value is only added to the result array when it is not one of your "banned" values. Thus the result array might be *shorter* than the input, which `.map()` really can't do.

Comment: That makes sense, or at least the way you explained it. The actual code is a bit fuzzy to me, so I hadn't realized it returned an array as its value. Either way, `.filter()` seems to be the easier to understand and use method to do the same thing your answer does, and I'd rather use an easy route that makes sense than one I have trouble understanding, in case I view my code in the future. Thanks for explaining it.